# Styles and images served by nginx in docker are not working on a page

Tags: docker, go, nginx, docker-compose

I have a golang webapp and I decided to use Nginx in front of it to serve static files and use it as a reverse proxy for my webapp.

Dockerfile for webapp:

```
FROM golang:1.21.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . ./

RUN go build -o ./bin/site ./cmd/site/main.go

CMD ["./bin/site"]
```

Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro"
      - "./site/assets/:/app/assets/"

  site:
    build: ./site
    container_name: tmp-site
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./site/views:/app/views"
```

And nginx config:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name tmp.loc www.tmp.loc;

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|html|svg)$ {
            root /app/assets/;

            expires max;
            access_log off;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://tmp-site:5555;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    Host                 $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

On the webpage I have two images, one png and one svg, the css file is simple and contains only `background-color: lightblue` for a body tag, and also js file which is just console logging a string "Loaded!". After starting up my containers with docker compose I have following problems:

1. Static files are served randomly, e.g. png image is displayed but svg is not, css styles are not applied to the page, but javascript code have executed fine. The funny part is that all of the static files are successfully fetched according to the browser's devtools network tab and you can check its content and yes, I've tried to reload the page without cache to no avail. What kind of magic is that?
2. As you can see in my docker compose file I set up volumes for both nginx and webapp and in case of nginx it works fine, whenever I remove some of assets and reload page without cache the changes are applied, but when I change the text in a template it is not visible on the page but if I will go inside webapp's container and check the content of template - it's changed but on the page it's not visible until I restart containers with docker compose. What's the issue here?

The full code is here - https://github.com/ivnku/tmp

Comment: For your second question: https://github.com/gofiber/template
`// Reload the templates on each render, good for development
 engine.Reload(true) // Optional. Default: false`

Comment: And for your first question: Yes they're being fetched, but not with the right mime type. You need to include `include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;` in the http section of the nginx.conf

Comment: @HamedN. daang it I didn't even notice that Content-Type header of fetched files is wrong, you're absolutely right! And thanks for the templates rendering hint. Can you create an answer so I will mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. gofiber's [template](https://github.com/gofiber/template)  provides this functionality by `Engine.Reload(true)`:

```golang
// Reload the templates on each render, good for development
engine.Reload(true) // Optional. Default: false
```

2. Static files are indeed being served by Nginx, just without the right mime type. Including mime types in the `http` section of nginx.conf will resolve this issue:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {
        ...
    }
}
```